# table beamer frame

Tags: tables, beamer

If I do a break in a cell the frame will be to short in the next lines (column 2 and 3). I am using the documentclass beamer.

```
\begin{frame}{Prüffziffersysteme}
\begin{block}{Übersicht über auftretende Eingabefehler}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|} 
\hline 
Fehlertyp & Symbol & relative Häufigkeit \tabularnewline
\hline
Einzelfehler\\ (Verwechslung einer Ziffer) & a \rightarrow b  & 79,0\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
Nachbar-Transpositionen\\ (Vertauschung benachbarter Ziffern) & ab \rightarrow ba & 10,2\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
Sprungtransposition\\ (Vertauschung einer Ziffer\\ mit der Übernächsten) & abc \rightarrow cba & 0,8\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
Zwillingsfehler & aa \rightarrow bb & 0,6\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
phonetische Fehler\\ (z.B.: dreißig - dreizehn) & a0 \leftrightarrow 1a \ (a=3,...,9) & 0,5\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
Sprung-Zwilling-Fehler\\ übrige Fehler (zufällige Fehler) & aca \rightarrow bcb & 0,3\%  \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The breaking inside a cell may be done with either `\newline` or `\par`. Here, `\\` will break the row at that point, ie, after first cell.

You may also use "p" (for paragraph) as the alignment character instead of "c" in `tabular`.

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|c|c|} 
\hline 
Fehlertyp & Symbol & relative Häufigkeit \tabularnewline
\hline
Einzelfehler\newline (Verwechslung einer Ziffer) & $ a \rightarrow b$    &     79,0\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
Nachbar-Transpositionen\newline (Vertauschung benachbarter Ziffern) &$ ab     \rightarrow ba$ & 10,2\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
Sprungtransposition\newline (Vertauschung einer Ziffer\newline mit der     Übernächsten) & $abc \rightarrow cba$ & 0,8\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
Zwillingsfehler & $aa \rightarrow bb$ & 0,6\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
phonetische Fehler\newline (z.B.: dreißig - dreizehn) & $a0     \leftrightarrow 1a \ (a=3,...,9) $ & 0,5\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
Sprung-Zwilling-Fehler\newline übrige Fehler (zufällige Fehler) & $aca     \rightarrow bcb $& 0,3\%  \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Prüffziffersysteme}
\begin{block}{Übersicht über auftretende Eingabefehler}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|} 
\hline 
Fehlertyp & Symbol & relative Häufigkeit \tabularnewline
\hline
Einzelfehler& &\\ (Verwechslung einer Ziffer) & $a \rightarrow b$  & 79,0\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
Nachbar-Transpositionen & &\\ (Vertauschung benachbarter Ziffern) & $ab \rightarrow ba$ & 10,2\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
Sprungtransposition & &\\ (Vertauschung einer Ziffer & &\\ mit der Übernächsten) & $abc \rightarrow cba$ & 0,8\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
Zwillingsfehler & $aa \rightarrow bb$ & 0,6\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
phonetische Fehler & &\\ (z.B.: dreißig - dreizehn) & $a0 \leftrightarrow 1a \ (a=3,...,9)$& 0,5\% \tabularnewline
\hline 
Sprung-Zwilling-Fehler & &\\ übrige Fehler (zufällige Fehler) & $aca \rightarrow bcb$ & 0,3\%  \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: tblrequired]